# Dynamic JavaScript object with colon

Tags: javascript

I want to create dynamic JavaScript object as follows. I tried with looping the object but I failed to achieve that task.

This is the object I need:

```
var aposition = {
    d6: 'bK',
    d4: 'wP',
    e4: 'wK'
};
```

But I got Like this

```
 object x: "a1:"bR",b2:"bR",c6:"bP",f6:"wQ",g7:"wR",h2:"wK""
```

JavaScript Code

```
response.forEach(function (entry) {
    positionLocate += entry.Coordination + ':' + '"' + entry.Piece.Code.replace(/"/g, '') + '"' + ',';
});
```

Comment: Just an advice, when you are pitching a problem, narrate it as if you are explaining it to a layman and provide facts accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are doing a string concatenation and expecting to build an object.

**Solution:**
You need to add `key` and `value` like this.

```
var aposition = {}; // declare a object
response.forEach(function (entry) {
  aposition[entry.Coordination] = entry.Piece.Code.replace(/"/g, '');// aposition[key] = value
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeshekar It's really helpfull to me. It's work ..